# Создание эффекта раскрытия изображения

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

Как можно создать эффект раскрытия изображения, когда нажимаешь в ленте на такое же более маленькое? Подобное есть во всех месседжерах и соцсетях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FrescoImageViewer](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer) здесь вполне подойдет. Насколько помню, это форкнутая кастомизация [PhotoDraweeView](https://github.com/ongakuer/PhotoDraweeView), в которой имеется какая-то проблема с горизонтальным переключением между изображениями, поэтому смотрите сами, нужен ли вам кастомный функционал.